# looping through a List<string[]>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, arraylist, asp.net-core

I am trying to get the values for each item with index inside array list i did it with this code but don't have values display after loop finished.

```
foreach (var item in (List<string[]>)TempData["verification_errors"])
{
    <p>@item[0].ToString() + @item[2].ToString()</p>
}
```

this is the `List<string[]>`

```
List<string[]> Data_verification_errors = new List<string[]>();
string[] Cust_Surname = new string[] { "CustomerSurname", reservation_details.CustomerSurname, "Customer name must have at least 2 characters" };

Data_verification_errors.Add(Cust_Surname);
```

Comment: What *is* `TemData`? If it is really an `ArrayList` the cast to `List<string[]>`should fail and you´d get an `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: Don't you need to deserialize your TempData into a list object first before looping through it?

Comment: I suppose OP means a list of arrays, a `List<string[]>`. That´s not an `ArrayList` however, so you should clreaifiy your question.

Comment: @HimBromBeere  temp data i store the array-list inside it ,to send it the view

Comment: tempdata is the arrray list

Comment: Avoid the term `ArrayList`, as this is the name of an (old) .NET-class and thus leads to confusion. What you probably mean instead is *a list of arrays*.

Comment: @hashim: no, that seems to be a `HashTable`

Comment: Why do you have a list that has only one single element (which itself is an array?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Presumably it's just an example, and that in real code there will be more than just the one item.

Comment: what i did and  trying to do , i have an array list after i fill or add with the values i pass it to tempdata to send it to view then loop through this tempdata and get the value

Comment: Your question is still tagges 'arraylist'. Don't keep it so wrong and sloppy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change inside the loop to:

```
<p>@(item[0].ToString() + item[2].ToString())</p>
```

instead of:

```
<p>@item[0].ToString() + @item[2].ToString()</p>
```

Comment: i have problem this text or value in `<p>@(item[0].ToString() + item[2].ToString())</p> ` dose not appear on the browser i don't know the reason

Comment: Do they have values?

Comment: Have you checked the source code to see if it exIsts? It might be in a display:none class or you might be missIng an end tag or something

Comment: also when i set this `<p>test</p>` inside for-each loop dose not appear also